# Call TCP send (net package) from http request function

Tags: go

I'm new to Go - following problem: My program receives an http post request and now I want to forward data from it to an active TCP connection (the program runs a parallel TCP Server).
In `main()` the handler is registered like this:
`http.HandleFunc("/rcvtelegram", handleRestRequest)`

and the http-handler function is therefore like this:

`func handleRestRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}`

The TCP connection to the client is open with a net.Conn object which `main()` knows. So ideally I would start a go routine with a TCP sender function that listens for an incoming string to send it through TCP. But how? With channels it seems I must pass all parameters but I don't have the connection object in the http handler function. I also want to avoid making the tcp connection a global variable. I saw the Observer pattern but that scares me with its complexity as a newbie (and not sure if it solves my problem).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a struct type to hold the channel.  Implement the [http.Handler](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Handler) interface on the type:

```
type RestHandler struct {
    ch chan string
}

func (h *RestHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // insert body of the handleRestRequest here.
    // Use h.ch <- someString to send string to connection
}
```

In your main function, create a channel for the TCP sender and start the sender in a goroutine:

```
ch := make(chan string)
go tcpSender(ch)
```

Create a value of *RestHandler with the channel and register it as the handler:

```
http.Handle("/rcvtelegram", &RestHandler{ch:ch})
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, you've set me on the right track. I'll comment my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above proposal I built it this way:

```
type TcpHandler struct {
    connection net.Conn
}
```

Then defined a custom HTTP Handler:

```
func (t TcpHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {...}
```

Then registered it with the existing TCP connection in `main()`:

```
httpTcpHandler := TcpHandler{connection: conn}
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/rcvtelegram", httpTcpHandler)
go startHttpServer(httpPort, mux)
```

Works as it should!